# Boost shared_ptr unable to implictly cast to templated base

Tags: c++, templates, boost, shared-ptr

The question is why I am getting the following error and how it can be fixed:

```
error C2664: 'work<T>::setPrev' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'
```

The call to function setPrev in class cCapital gives the error.

```
template <class T> class work
{
    public:
        work(const T & value):m_prev(), m_data(value) {}
        ~work(){}

        boost::shared_ptr<work> getPrev() const {return m_prev;}
        const T & value() const {return data;}
        void setPrev(boost::shared_ptr<work> elem) {m_prev = elem;}
        void setValue(const T & value) {data = value;}

    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<work> m_prev;
        T m_data;
};

class cAssetBase
{
    public:
        cAssetBase(const std::string & desc):m_desc(desc){}
        ~cAssetBase(){}
        const std::string & getDesc() const
        {
            return m_desc;
        }
    private:
        std::string m_desc;
};  

class cAsset: public work<cAssetBase>
{
    public:
        cAsset(const int & id, const std::string & symbol):m_id(id),work(cAssetBase(symbol)){}
        ~cAsset(){}
    protected:
        int m_id;
};

class cCapitalBase
{
    public:
        cCapitalBase(const std::string & desc):m_desc(desc){}
        ~cCapitalBase(){}
        const std::string & getDesc() const
        {
            return m_desc;
        }
    private:
        std::string m_desc;
};  

class cCapital: public work<cCapitalBase>
{
    public:
        cCapital(const int & id, const std::string & symbol, boost::shared_ptr<cAsset> & asset):m_id(id),work(cCapitalBase(symbol)),m_asset(asset)
        {
            setPrev(m_asset);
        }
        ~cCapital(){}
    protected:
        int m_id;
        boost::shared_ptr<cAsset>  m_asset;
};
```

Comment: You realize that `work<A>` and `work<B>` are unrelated types, right? A shared pointer of one is not convertible to a shared pointer of the other.

Comment: Ah, I see, is there a way around this?

Comment: That's too vague a question. You need to design your solution to fit your problem, but it depends entirely on the details.